# Unable to import .svg attachments files Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to import .svg files in Wordpress using Wordpress Importer.

I am using below code.

**In functions.php File**

```
    function businessplus_mime_types($mimes) {
        $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
        return $mimes;
    }

    add_filter('upload_mimes', 'businessplus_mime_types');
    add_filter('mime_types', 'businessplus_mime_types');
```

**In wp-config.php File**

```
    define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '500M');
```

Comment: Try to change your filter by
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'businessplus_mime_types', 1, 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can import .svg files in wordpress. By using the below code.

In functions.php

```
function businessplus_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
    return $mimes;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes', 'businessplus_mime_types');
add_filter('mime_types', 'businessplus_mime_types');
```

and need to replace 'fetch_remote_file' function in wordpress-importer.php file in Wordpress Importer Plugin. 'fetch_remote_file' function should be replaced by the below code.

```
function fetch_remote_file($url, $post) {
            $file_name = basename($url);

            $remote_get = wp_remote_get($url);
            $upload = wp_upload_bits($file_name, 0, wp_remote_retrieve_body($remote_get), $post['upload_date']);

        $this->url_remap[$url] = $upload['url'];
            $this->url_remap[$post['guid']] = $upload['url']; 

            return $upload;
        }
```